# `grep` cause bash script stop

Tags: bash, shell, grep

```
##!/bin/bash
set -e
cat << EOF > file1
1
2
3
EOF
cat << EOF > file2
1
2
3
4
EOF
a=$(grep -v -F -x -f file1 file2)
echo 'aa'
b=$(grep -v -F -x -f file2 file1)
echo 'bb not run'
```

When I run above bash script `sudo bash ./***.sh`,`b=$(grep -v -F -x -f file2 file1)` cause script stop.
How to fix this problem?

Comment: What is purpose of `set -e`?

Comment: You are getting non-zero exit code from `grep` hence `set -e` is causing script to exit.

Comment: `grep` returns a nonzero exit status if it doesn't match anything. `set -e` makes the script stop if any of the commands return a nonzero status.

Comment: There should be a single `#` at the beginning of the shebang. I can see no reason to use `sudo` to run this.

Comment: @tripleee,as cannot log in root,I always `sudo`

Comment: @anubhava,if some typo mistake,`set -e` can notice the error.

Comment: I must `set -e`,any solution to this question?

Comment: @kittygirl, `set -e` reduces reliability, it doesn't increase it. See [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) for a detailed discussion (below the parable at the top there's a set of exercises). Anyone who claims to be an "expert" and is telling you to use `set -e` is not.

Comment: @kittygirl, ...that said, for any command where you want `set -e` to not exit, put `||:` on the end; so, f/e, `a=$(grep -v -F -x -f file1 file2) ||:`.

Comment: https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/ is also worth reading -- it goes into how different shells implement `set -e` in slightly different ways (meaning that you're getting reduced reliability and portability when depending on it). That's also true in that `set -e` behavior is different between different _versions_ of bash, so it exposes you to version-specific bugs.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy,thanks for your comments.If I want bash quit when error occur,any alternative to `set -e`?

Comment: Nothing here needs any privileges; you don't need either of `root` or `sudo` to run this script.

Comment: Charles [already told you the alternative,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68291677/grep-cause-bash-script-stop?noredirect=1#comment120695715_68291677) as do the answers to the duplicate question. In case you missed it, if `grep` can fail but you don't want that to cause the script to terminate, use `grep || true` or equivalently `grep || :` or, in more longhand, `if ! grep then; true; fi`

Comment: ...whereas if you _want_ the shell to exit after a nonzero exit status from a given command, put `|| exit` after that individual command. (That a "nonzero exit staus" and an "error" are not exactly the same thing is part of why `set -e` is unreliable: it assumes that all nonzero exit statuses are errors -- except where they're "checked" and it ignores them, a list of exceptions that varies between versions -- but what you have here is a `grep` that's emitting a nonzero status even when that doesn't really reflect an error as such).